# how to calculate module 2 in Python for two binary strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, jupyter-notebook, cryptography

So l have a homework to do,

I need to simulate **the Vernam cipher** (**adding two binary strings by module 2**) for 3 different inputs:
**text, image and pseudorandom array**.
But l cant figure it out how to do module for binary strings..

Please help :(

Comment: do you mean something like 0b101 % 0b10 = 1 i.e., 5%2=1?

Comment: by `adding ... by module 2` do you mean just `xor`?

Comment: I meant **mod** operation just like @sai wrote
1. case is text inputs, l have to simulate Vernam cipher by adding two binery strings by mod 2
2. case is image input for same thing
3. case is pseudorandom array

Comment: You really don't know you want. "mod 2 addition" of bits is just `xor`, as @AAAlex123 noted, yet you accepted an answer that has nothing at all to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work-

```py
def bin_string_to_int(s):
   breakdown = [int(d)*2**n for n,d in enumerate(reversed(s))]
   # breakdown.reverse() # to check the exponents
   return sum(breakdown)

b1 = "101" # 5 in binary 
b1_in_int = bin_string_to_int(b1)

b2 = "10" # 2 in binary
b2_in_int = bin_string_to_int(b2)

print(b1_in_int % b2_in_int)
```